# How can I compress many files in a solid archive, but quickly extract only one?

Tags: compression, archive, xz, zstd

I have 14,000 25 MB files that I am trying to compress to minimum size for storage. At runtime, I will only need to decompress one or two of the files. There is sufficient intra-file redundancy that they compress reasonably well, but there is also sufficient inter-file redundancy that taring first doubles the compression ratio:

```
Individual files, compressed with "xz -9": 65 GB total
Single tar blob, compressed with "xz -9": 33 GB
```

**Is there a way to compress a set of files in such a way that the compressor can take advantage of inter-file redundancy, but the decompressor does not need to decompress all data?** Extracting a 33GB tar at runtime would be untenable. I can use a compressor library API directly, but would prefer not to heavily modify the library itself.

I tried using `zstd`, training a dictionary from the full file set, the compressing with that dictionary, but it showed no improvement in compression ratio whatsoever (zstd dictionaries seem to only help with very small files).

Comment: The zstd trainer produces a 110k dictionary by default. Did you try playing around with the size of the dictionary using --maxdict=#. Maybe try 1mb?

Comment: Yup, I also tried setting maxdict to 1MB and 10MB but didn't see a difference